# Template URL path is not getting loaded in angular js

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I am trying to use angular js routing for page navigation .

'When' block is getting executed but the required jsp file is not getting loaded .I check the status on browser developer tools .

Below is my project structure . 
[image: Project Structure]

Js file .

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

       app.config(function($routeProvider) {
              alert("HI2");
               $routeProvider
               .when('/home.web', {

                templateUrl : '/Views/Home.jsp',
                controller  : 'MyController'
            })
            .when('/angularJS.web', {
               templateUrl : 'angularJS.jsp',
                 controller  : 'MyController'
            })
            .when('/ProductMix.web', {
                      templateUrl : 'ProductMix.jsp',
                    controller  : 'MyController'
               })
               .otherwise({
                           redirectTo: '/home.web'
                     });


       });
```

Is the correct way to provide template URL path ??

Comment: Don't you have any errors in your browser development tools ?

Comment: why do some paths have `/Views` and others don't? Why does `/Views` have leading `/` and others don't? Did you try these paths in browser address bar manually? What is status in dev tools network?